# Function gets() Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, glibc

I have to do a very simple task in assembly: read input from the user (name) and then output this input.

The way I have to do it - to use function `gets()`. I know that this function should never be used but teacher specified the task to do it using only `gets` function.

The problem I face - whenever I call this function and enter my input it gives me Segmentation fault. I make buffer size equal to 24 bytes just for example.

It doesn't matter how much memory I give this function on stack - always the same mistake. One interesting thing: if I `leaq -(k*24)(%rsp), %rsp` and then `mov %rsp, %rdi` and then calling `gets` will allow me to enter as many inputs as I want and never stop. It happens with only number 24 and any `k` you want.

Why could it happen?

Thank you.

Function `name`

```
.string1:
       .string "Please enter your name: "
.string2:
       .string "Hello, %s"


.globl name

name:
     push %rbx
     push %rbp             #calee saved regs

     leaq -24(%rsp),%rsp         # name_str[24]
     mov %rsp, %rbp              #save rsp

     movq $.string1, %rdi
     xorl %eax,%eax
     call printf

     movq %rsp, %rdi
     call gets
     movq $.string2, %rdi
     mov %rax, %rsi
     xorl %eax, %eax
     call printf
     ret
```

UPDATE1: Sorry for not mentioning earlier: I have main written in `C`, it just simply calls the function:

```
     #include <stdlib.h>
     void name(void);
     void main()
     {
         name();
         return;
     }
```

UPDATE2: I'm using `Linux 64bit` and `GCC 4.8.4` (quite old, I know)

UPDATE3: Using `gcc -o exec main.c name.s` to link.

Comment: [why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). **edit**....so, change your teacher/school

Comment: @LPs If I had enough money I would do it half a year ago:)

Comment: You sure the code crashes during the `gets`? Because it most definitely crashes when you attempt to `ret` to the wrong address (everything you pushed must be popped before you return!).

Comment: `leaq -24(%rsp),%rsp` is also equivalent to `sub rsp,24`, which I find easier to read (also it sort of hints what to do to restore the `rsp` before `ret`).

Comment: @LPs at least their using Linux 64bit, which really surprises me. A lot of students at these high priced institutions are being taught assembly using DOS 1.0

Comment: What OS and C compiler are you using? Getting the calling convention right here is critical to getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The changes I've made have already been pointed out to you, but as you've got 90% of it, thought I'd fix it up for you. There probably will be comments about `ENTER`, but the point is, we're making something work, not worry about optimization.

Your version wouldn't link either, as GCC is going to expect `main` as the entry point, unless you passed `-e name` to the linker.

```
.string1:
       .string "Please enter your name: "
.string2:
       .string "Hello, %s\n"


.globl main

main:
        enter   $80, $0

        movl    $.string1, %edi
        call    printf

        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        call    gets

        movl    $.string2, %edi
        mov     %rax, %rsi
        call    printf

        leave
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you not save rsp into rbp before increasing the stack size? Also should you not clean up rsp and rbp before leaving tge function?